# Recursos necessários por formula

Tags: python-3.x

Sou autodidata e estou ainda em aprendizado. Então não sei qual formula seria melhor (consome menos recurso de hardware: cpu e memória)

Qual delas consome menos em Python 3?

> 1

```
from random import randint

maior = menor = 0

for i in range(3):  
    n = randint(1, 100)  
    print(n)  
    if i == 0:  
        menor = n  
        maior = n  
    else:  
        if n < menor:  
            menor = n  
        if n > maior:  
            maior = n

print(maior, menor)
```

> 2

```
numeros[randint(1, 100), randint(1, 100), randint(1, 100)]
print(numeros)
print(min(numeros), max(numeros))
```

> 3

```
numeros = [randint(1, 100), randint(1, 100), randint(1, 100)]
print(numeros)

maior = (lambda n: max(n))(numeros)
menor = (lambda n: min(n))(numeros)

print(menor, maior)
```

Comment: Não faz diferença, está usando Python em um problema minúsculo. Se quer menor consumo faça em um problema que valha a pena em uma linguagem que preza por isto e dá facilidades para lidar com essa necessidade.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Mas é questão de estudo mesmo não de aplicação. É só uma duvida geral. Mas obrigado mesmo assim.

Comment: Mesmo assim preciso quem alguém me ajude a saber quanto consome. Tenho 35 anos e estou estudando Python 3 junto com meu sobrinho de 10 anos para incentivar a ele estudar programação e Python tem uma boa curva de aprendizado pra quem esta começando.

Comment: Agora faz menos sentido ainda se preocupar com isto. Se preocupar com as coisas erradas é desensinar.

Comment: Este tipo de optimizações não são interessantes. Optimizar código a este nível só resulta no que se chama de legacy code. Python gere memória por si. Não só quer isso dizer que não terá que se preocupar, quer também dizer que poderá mudar sem ninguem lhe pedir opinião. Pode explorar complexidade algoritmica se realmente pretende entender com complexidade é calculada em algoritmos. Sem querer o deixar sem uma resposta, pode utilizar o modulo `dis` para analizar byte code python e perceber como a VM python funciona. Preocupe-se em o código ser legível acima de tudo.

Comment: Muito obrigado Pedro.

Comment: É legal você querer saber deste tipo de coisa, mas não neste contexto em que quer aplicar. Acaba sendo perda de energia em algo que não muda nada (mesmo que te respondessem detalhadamente, o uso real e prático seria nulo e nada garante que sempre vá ser assim) sendo que tem coisas muito mais importantes para se preocupar em relação à linguagem escolhida. É basicamente o que o Maniero ja disse, não ponha foco onde você não tem um problema de fato, ainda mais no estágio em que descreveu estar e por se tratar de uma linguagem que não foi feita para quem precisa desse tipo de microotimização .

Comment: Obrigado Bacco. Tanto que vou manter a pergunta e as resposta que achei ótimas, mas mudei a Tag só pra Python 3x pra não atrapalhar outras pesquisar.
Obrigado a Todos!

Comment: acho que vc pode usar time it para fazer testes

Answer (score 0):

O consumo é mínimo em suas funções, mas se quer realmente saber aconselharia utilizar o módulo **timeit** , você terá o tempo de execução de cada função acredito que consequentemente a que levar menor tempo é a que exige menos recursos de processamento.

```
from random import randint
import timeit
def maior_menor():

    maior = menor = 0

    for i in range(3):  
        n = randint(1, 100)  
        print(n)  
        if i == 0:  
             menor = n  
             maior = n  
        else:  
            if n < menor:  
                menor = n  
            if n > maior:  
                maior = n

    print(maior, menor)
def menor_maior():
     numeros[randint(1, 100), randint(1, 100), randint(1, 100)]
     print(numeros)
     print(min(numeros), max(numeros))
t = timeit.Timer("maior_menor(1,1000from __main__ import maior_menor")
print t.repeat()
t = timeit.Timer("menor_maior(1,1000from __main__ import menor_maior")
print t.repeat()
```